# How to set my toolbar fixed while scrolling android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I am currently working in e-commerce android app, i need to fix the toolbar while scrolling.

As i attached the screenshot below. while scrolling the action bar need to be fixed and the body content scroll behind the toolbar

[image]

Here is the layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_reg"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="3dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />


        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:hint="@string/reg_name"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:hint="@string/reg_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:hint="@string/reg_password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_cpassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_cpassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:hint="Confirm Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_mobile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_mobile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:hint="Mobile No"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_dob"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_dob"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:hint="Date of Birth" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Permanent Address" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/btn_sign_up"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/link_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/req_login"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Post your layout and activity/fragment code. That is default behavior in android, content normally scrolls behind the action bar.  So if it is scrolling over your action bar then you are doing something in your layout.

Comment: Naveed i have attached my layout below, kindly check it and let me know asap

Comment: I do not see a root view in your layout.  You should move all of your scroll view inside your Linear layout.

Comment: it working fine after moving scroll view inside my Linear layout

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should structure your XML so that it's like this:

```
Relative layout
|-->Toolbar    (android:id="@+id/toolbar")
|-->ScrollView (android:layout_below="@id/toolbar")
    |-->ViewGroup(For example, CoordinatorLayout)
        |-->Child
        |-->Child
        |-->Child
```

Example code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:theme="@style/WelcomeActivityTheme.Toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        />
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, moreover you don't need to set the toolbar height to 56 dp, `android:layout_height="match_parent"` works also well.

Comment: Scroll view can only have 1 child isnt it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your posted layout does not seem to have a root view.

However to fix the scrolling problem you need to move your scroll view under the same parent as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_reg"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="3dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />


        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:hint="@string/reg_name"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:hint="@string/reg_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:hint="@string/reg_password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_cpassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_cpassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:hint="Confirm Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_mobile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_mobile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:hint="Mobile No"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_dob"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_dob"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:hint="Date of Birth" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Permanent Address" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/btn_sign_up"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/link_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/req_login"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given Root view is RelativeLayout in your xml
You should set in scrollview xml

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/container_toolbar"
    android:elevation="3dp">
```

and remove margin_top from linear layout below scrollview tag.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many ways to keep the `toolbar` fixed, while not resizing or compressing the layout by `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`, that is not a proper.

That is only possible by Coordinator layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:ripple="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           android:id="@+id/tv_toolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="50dp"
           android:background="#fff"
           ripple:contentInsetStart="0dp">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/coordinate_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:marginTop="56dp">
</ScrollView>
```

Keep the structure as

```
   Coordinator layout
  |-->Toolbar    (android:id="@+id/toolbar")
  |-->ScrollView (android:layout_below="@id/toolbar")
   |-->Child
   |-->Child
   |-->Child
```