# How to make toolbar fixed while scrolling in android?

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar, android-scroll

I have researched all the previous question before posting this question none of the previous solution worked for me. I need to make my `Toolbar` static while scrolling it goes up while scrolling butI need to make it static how can i do this. Now let me explain what are all the methods I have tried so far,

1. I have entered `windowSoftInputMode` to adjust resize
2. `fitwindows`
       true in layout

This is the code i have written :

This is the main `CoordinatorLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/activity_incident"
       />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the layout file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_incident"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/incident_recyclerview"
        android:divider="#fff"
         android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I just want to make my `Toolbar` static how can I achieve Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set my toolbar fixed while scrolling android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33506335/how-to-set-my-toolbar-fixed-while-scrolling-android)

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran you want to keep the tool bar in the same position or what does this mean again   *need to make my tool bar static while scrolling it goes up while scrolling but i need to make it static*

Comment: nothing to do with layout will i not work with coordinator layout

Comment: @Charuක hello i don't want the toolbar moves it needs to be static

Comment: Add Nested ScrollView after AppBarLayout it will work.

Answer (score 6):

Remove `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` this from `Toolbar` and check scroll.

Answer (score 4):

Okay there are lot of answers but ,

### Is this what are you looking for?

[image] [image]

If yes, you can use **[CollapsingToolbarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html)**

For the second view here is my xml all you need to remove `ImageView` to get the first view.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/monkey"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffe5e5e5"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/activity_second" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Take a note that I've used  `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` for `Toolbar`

Have fun ^_^

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran have you checked this answer

Answer (score 0):

Make your layout like this. Your toolbar will be fixed at top while you scroll your layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
        app:statusBarScrim="@color/primary"
        app:contentScrim="@color/primary"
        app:titleEnabled="false"
        app:layout_collapseMode="none"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


        <!--
        we must create the value entry for the toolbar height here as different version would have different heights
        -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:gravity="top"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp">


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/activity_incident"
       />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```